# Error in activity when adding another activity "switcher"

Tags: android, android-activity, apk

I get some errors with my main activity code when adding another activity "switcher"

Here are my code:

```
package com.frede.fusrodah;


public class FusRoDAHActivity extends Activity {


  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
       return;
  }
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FusRoDAH.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
                next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FusRoDAHnommusic.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);



                    }
            }


        );
    }
}
```

I get some errors with some "}" Can somebody help me correct it?

I wrote this code and then it kinda broke?

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
                next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FusRoDAHnommusic.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

Comment: why you are embedding a button in click event of another button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you where looking for....

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FusRoDAH.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}
});
Button next2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
next2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FusRoDAHnommusic.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}
});
}
```

If not what you wanna to do exactly?